# Purging Workflow Audit Data

Tags: 2013-sp1, workflow

So we were using [Workflow Auditing](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-2264235C-36D3-4A42-8545-F5B79868ADCB) for one of our client, but later we decided to turn it off because:

1. We were hardly using it
2. The Auditing Snapshots of Content must have been consuming a lot of DB Storage.

Now, after turning it off we now want to purge the Workflow Auditing Data.

Is there any power shell script available for it explicitly or it is taken care when we [purge Workflow Process Histories](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-3A6C6B63-8B2A-4F37-B588-C72CA70B7A83)?

Answer (score 6):

It is indeed taken care of when you purge your Workflow Process Histories.  I don't think there is a way to purge the "snapshots" without purging the entire Process History.